# Serial Chart in amCharts showing different beahaviour

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am using [amCharts](https://www.amcharts.com/) for my App. Recently I updated it from version `3.17.0` to `3.20.6`.

In my App, I have used export with `capture` method to capture image as below:

```
if (window.fabric) {
                    clearTimeout(interval);

                    // CAPTURE CHART
                    chart.export.capture({}, function() {

                        // SAVE TO JPG
                        this.toPNG({}, function(base64) {

                            //some code
                                                    });
                    });
                }
 }, 10);
```

In my serial chart with Chart cursor, It was working fine as below in previous version. See image:[image: amChart version 3.17.0]

After updating version it shows weird behavior: ChartCursor gone, and on dragging cursor it is drawing line on Chart.  [image: amChart version 3.20.6]

I have checked on amChart website, I have correctly set everything.

What can be wrong here?

If I will disable chart.export.capture, it' will working fine.

Here is my code to set properties chart:

```
"type": "serial",
                "theme": "none",
                "pathToImages": "resources/javascript/amcharts/images/",
                "marginTop": 1,
                "marginBottom": 1,
                "autoMarginOffset": offsetM,
                //left hand side space between container and chart
                "zoomOutButtonRollOverAlpha": 0.15,

                "zoomControl": {
                    "zoomControlEnabled": true,
                    "backgroundAlpha": "0.15",
                    "backgroundColor": "#000000"
                },

                "dataProvider": valueChartData,
                "columnWidth": 1,
                "categoryField": "date",
                "categoryAxis": {
                    "minPeriod": "DD",
                    "parseDates": true
                },

                "export": {
                    "enabled": false,
                    "menu": []
                }
```

for exporting and cloning chart:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
                    if (window.fabric) {
                        clearTimeout(interval);

                        // CAPTURE CHART
                        main.pageContainerBulkMarketing.bulkmarketing.pageContainerBMReports.reports.chart["export"].capture({}, function() {

                            // SAVE TO JPG
                            this.toPNG({}, function(base64) {

                                somewhere.OpenedTabGrpClone = "";
                                somewhere.OpenedTabGrpClone = base64;
                            });
                        });
                    }
                }, 10);
```

Note: I have observed one thing: It is adding one canvas tag over our chart div, it is like:

```
<canvas class="upper-canvas " style="position: absolute; width: 802px; height: 360px; left: 0px; top: 0px; -moz-user-select: none; cursor: crosshair;" width="802" height="360"></canvas>
```

UPDATE: Here I have added [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/La99s5uo/) But, here it is working fine, I took this time to figure out that why it's not working my side; result :none.

Comment: Do you get any errors in browser's console? Or maybe have a link for us to check?

Comment: amm.. no, no any errors in browser console. I can update here more related code if you need.

Comment: actually the canvas control make the issue , check which code create canvas control .

Comment: Can you set up a working example on codepen or jsfiddle? Without it it's just guessing and trying to filling in the gaps.

Comment: your graph seem correct showing , but canvas replace over the mouse cursor point area

Comment: @NazirUllah Yes, it makes sense. in jsfiddle I see, that new chart is rendering just below original chart(inside canvas tag). But in my App, it is overriding on my original Chart.

Comment: I check it on separate aspx page it is working fine, but on your app it may interfere with other js or plugin check all links included on such page, and also test with live amchart lib links .may it work

Comment: @NazirUllah Finally I manged it by setting Z-index by -1 for canvas tag. thanx

Comment: @NazirUllah When do you set the z-index for canvas? Using JS in one of the events, or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple do this

**1)** Check your library links and plugin code , may it interfer with other js or plugin .

**2)** Also Test your code with live amchart libraries.

**3)** if every thing fine and working set Z-index by -1 for canvas tag.